# gcloud domains list without ssl certificates

Tags: regex, gcloud

I wish to list the app engine custom domains that do not have an ssl certificate.  See the [topic filters documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters).

for example:

`gcloud beta app domain-mappings list --limit=20 --format=json --filter="sslSettings.certificateId:(*)"`

produces the opposite of what I seek.

Sample response JSON FYI  (I named some variables in {}):

```
{
"id": "*.{domain}",
"name": "apps/{projectId}/domainMappings/*{domain}",
"resourceRecords": [
  {
    "name": "*",
    "rrdata": "{sub}.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com",
    "type": "CNAME"
  }
],
"sslSettings": {
  "certificateId": "1234567",
  "sslManagementType": "MANUAL"
}
```

The response I seek has no `sslSettings` field at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filter you have produces the opposite of what you need, you just have to negate it:

```
--filter='NOT sslSettings.certificateId:(*)'
```

See [`gcloud topic filters`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) for more information.

But you already did the hard part :)